# Actionbar back button not functioning as needed

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to make a note app. Basically when i click on an item in the list view this will take me to another activity when the name of the item is editable. When i edit the text and click the back button in the action bar, the text should be updated in the main activity,however this does not happen; but when i use the android back button (the one of the device) it works fine.

here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView MemoContent ;
static ArrayList<String> MyArray ;
static ArrayAdapter MyAdapter ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    MemoContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MemoContent) ;
    MyArray = new ArrayList<>() ;
    MyArray.add("Example Note") ;

     MyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , MyArray);
    MemoContent.setAdapter(MyAdapter);

    MemoContent.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , EditMemo.class) ;
            i.putExtra("note" , position) ;
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });

}
```

and here is the second activity

```
public class EditMemo extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher {

EditText editText ;
int id;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_memo);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText) ;

    Intent  j = getIntent() ;
    id = j.getIntExtra("note" , -1) ;
    if(id!=-1)
    {
        editText.setText(MainActivity.MyArray.get(id));
    }

    editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
}


@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    MainActivity.MyArray.set(id , String.valueOf(s)) ;
    MainActivity.MyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
```

}

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You have to handle the ActionBar back button by overriding `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` in your second activity .

Comment: When i created the second activity i used the hierarchy option to set the back button to the first activity.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to add the **meta-data** tag and the **android:parentActivityName** attribute to your child activity declaration in the manifest as follows:

```
 <activity
      android:name=".EditMemo"
      android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
          <meta-data
              android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
              android:value="full.package.name.to.MainActivity" />
   </activity>
```

If you are targeting API level 16 and up *just* the **android:parentActivityName** attribute is needed

Comment: Thank you, but the back button is already working; however when i return to the main activity i find that the element in the list did not change as i change the text in the memo, but if i returned with the android button it actually does change.

Comment: Did you try moving the notifyDataSetChanged call to MainActivity's onResume callback?